# Zienia Merton (SPACE:1999), RIP

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

British actress Zienia Merton, known for her role as "Sandra Benes" on the 1970's sci/fi tv series Space:1999 [passed away on September 14, 2018](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2018/sep/18/zienia-merton-obituary).

[image]
Though best known for her work on '1999, Merton's career spanned over five decades on a wide variety of British films and television programs.  Notable appearances within the science fiction genre included guest roles on Doctor Who, The Sarah Jane Adventures, and Wizards Vs. Aliens.  Merton also appeared in a number of British soap operas, such as Doctors, Coronation Street, and the long-running series EastEnders.

Merton was close friends with the late Martin Landau, whom she described as her [acting mentor and best friend](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0581617/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm)

Comment: I was a huge fan of SPACE:1999, and Sandra was one of my first crushes as a little kid.